# GLFW with vulkan, how to get rid of memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, glfw, vulkan

I am trying to use GLFW and vulkan in arch linux.

I noticed that I get a memory leak when calling `glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions`. To detect said memory leak, I simply call valgrind with my program.

Valgrind reports:

```
==13943== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13943==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==13943==    indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==13943==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

My code is:

```
int main() {
    glfwInit();
    uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions;
    glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out `glfwGetRequiredExtensions` valgrind reports no leaks.

In addition, I don;t want to try to free that memory myself because the documentation for that function says:

> Pointer lifetime:
>   The returned array is allocated and freed by GLFW. You should not free it yourself. It is guaranteed to be valid only until the library is terminated.

I know it's just 48 bytes, but I'd prefer to have no memory leaks, iif only for OCD sake.

Is there a way to appropriately avoid that issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with glfw, but assuming glfwTerminate is supposed to free the extension list (rather than some other call which you're not making), your only option is probably to debug where the leak is in glfw and fix it there.

Comment: According to the documentation it should free it. I also digged down the glfw code and there seems to be proper memory management deleting the pointers.

Comment: It it returning the the Wayland or X11 extensions?

Comment: My system only has x11

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling the Vk functions in `_glfwInitVulkan` to see if it's actually GLFW leaking, or the loader / Vulkan driver?

Comment: I have not. I will try when I get the opportunity

Comment: It's not obvious from looking at the source where the leak is.  The extensions that `glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions()` returns are not allocated and the `calloc()` that happens in `_glfwInitVulkan()` appears to get `free()`'d correctly.

Comment: ... following on it might be a [Vulkan issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/571).